# legend missing of function ppcomp in package fitdistrplus in R

Tags: r, plot, legend, fitdistrplus

I have a big data with more than 20 millions values, due to privacy and making the codes reproducible, I use mydata to replace it.

```
set.seed(1234)
mydata <- rlnorm(28000000,3.14,1.3)
```

I want to find which known distributions fit `mydata` best, so function `fitdist` in package `fitdistrplus` is choosen.

```
library(fitdistrplus)
fit.lnorm <- fitdist(mydata,"lnorm")
fit.weibull <- fitdist(mydata, "weibull")
fit.gamma <- fitdist(mydata, "gamma", lower = c(0, 0))
fit.exp <- fitdist(mydata,"exp")
```

Then, I use `ppcomp` function to draw P-P plot to help me choose the best fitted distribution.

```
library(RColorBrewer)
tiff("./pplot.tiff",res = 300,compression = "lzw",height = 6,width = 10,units = "in",pointsize = 12)
ppcomp(list(fit.lnorm,fit.weibull, fit.gamma,fit.exp), fitcol = brewer.pal(9,"Set1")[1:4],legendtext = c("lnorm","weibull", "gamma","exp"))
dev.off()
```

[image: pplot]
Absolutely, lognormal fits `mydata` best, but take a look at the `legend` of the plot, the line annotation with different colors is missing, only text annotation shows, what should I do?

I try some datasets with few values, and it worked. So the big data leads to the question, what should I do to make the legend perfect?

Comment: There must be a problem with your `legend` command in `ppcomp`, probably need to specify `lty`

Comment: @RichardTelford Yeah, you are right, what a stupid question!

Answer (score 0):

A lot of function questions could be done by `fix(function)`, in this way, we could know how the function works.

`fix(ppcomp)`

And I find some codes about legend,

```
if (addlegend) {
    if (missing(legendtext)) 
      legendtext <- paste("fit", 1:nft)
    if (!largedata) 
      legend(x = xlegend, y = ylegend, bty = "n", legend = legendtext, 
        pch = fitpch, col = fitcol, ...)
    else legend(x = xlegend, y = ylegend, bty = "n", legend = legendtext, 
      col = fitcol, ...)
  }
```

Then, I add `lty=1` to the legend, and it works.